# EntityFramework.SqlServer missing from nuget?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, nuget

**Context**

- Creating an Entity Framework data layer (experience with Hibernate)
- Connecting to SQL Server Express
- Client is a simple desktop application
- I can't use Entity Framework CORE

**Details**

I've been working through Entity Framework 6's docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/) as well as some other resources. Everything I've found in regards to EF6 is quite dated. Case in point it ["says"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/configuring/config-file#the-entity-framework-configuration-section) it'll add things to the config file when you install via nuget manager but doesn't...

> The entityFramework section was automatically added to the configuration file of your project when you installed the EntityFramework NuGet package.

Frustrating but I can work around that, not my first `app.config`.

**However** what confuses me further down in the Entity Framework docs is the provider registration. Nuget was supposed to install a reference to `EntityFramework.SqlServer`, but it never did. I could also not install it via nuget package manager. I managed to find it in [nuget.org](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework.SqlServer/) but is unlisted and hasn't been updated since 2015

```
<providers>
    <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" 
              type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
</providers>
```

**Question**

Do I still even need `EntityFramework.SqlServer`? I can easily add it in if I have too but is this the correct approach? Do people still use this old .dll out in the real world/prod?

I am curious to see how one with more experience with ET 6 would configure a fresh project.

**UPDATE - DEC-9-2019**

So digging into a little more, this behaviour doesn't work if you're installing Nuget packages with PackageReference rather than Package.config. You can change it by navigating to **Tools --> Options--> Nuget Package Manager --> General --> Default package management format**

Comment: `EntityFramework.SqlServer` is part of Entity Framework **Core** - not the "base" Entity Framework (v6.x) that's running on the full .NET framework

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just adding the EntityFramework NuGet package to your empty Windows Forms project should add the following references in your .csproj:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\EntityFramework.6.4.0\lib\net45\EntityFramework.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="EntityFramework.SqlServer, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\EntityFramework.6.4.0\lib\net45\EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System" />
    <Reference Include="System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations" />
    <Reference Include="System.Core" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml.Linq" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data.DataSetExtensions" />
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.CSharp" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data" />
    <Reference Include="System.Deployment" />
    <Reference Include="System.Drawing" />
    <Reference Include="System.Net.Http" />
    <Reference Include="System.Windows.Forms" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

And the following in your App.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
        <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
        <section name="entityFramework"
          type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
          requirePermission="false"/>
    </configSections>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2"/>
    </startup>
    <entityFramework>
        <providers>
            <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer"/>
        </providers>
    </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

Comment: So for clarification, this behaviour only works with the Package.config format within Tools --> Options--> Nuget Package Manager --> General --> Default package management format (at least for me). Prior to modifying it I had it set to PackageReference.

Comment: Marking as answered since it clarifies what 'should' happen